# How do I assign finite attribute points in my mini role-play code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python from Dawson, Programming for the absolute beginner and trying an assignment from chapter 5 to assign attribute points to a role-play hero. There are 30 points to spend, my code works well so far but breaks down once all 30 points are spent as it keeps going beyond zero.

How do I stop this programme when all points are spent?

CODE BELOW:

```
points = 30


Att = [["Strength", 0] , ["Health" , 0] , ["Wisdom" , 0] , ["Dexterity" , 0]]

    choice = ""

    while choice != "0":

            print ("\nYou have" , points , "points remaining")

            print ("""

0 - Exit
1 - Show Stats
2 - Assign Strength
3 - Assign Health
4 - Assign Wisdom
5 - Assign Dexterity

""")

            choice = input("\n\nChoice: ")

        if choice == "1":

        print ("\n")
        print (Att [0][0] , Att [0][1])
        print (Att [1][0] , Att [1][1])
        print (Att [2][0] , Att [2][1])
        print (Att [3][0] , Att [3][1])


        elif choice == "2":

             s = int(input("\nAdd points to Strength: "))

            Att [0][1] = Att [0][1] + s

            points = points - s

        elif choice == "3":

            h = int(input("\nAdd points to Health: "))

            Att [1][1] = Att [1][1] + h

            points = points - h

        elif choice == "4":

            w = int(input("\nAdd points to Wisdom: "))

            Att [2][1] += w

            points -= w

        elif choice == "5":

            d = int(input("\nAdd points to Dexterity: "))

            Att [3][1] += d

            points -= d

        elif choice == "0":


            input("Press enter if sure you have finished: ")
```

Comment: `while choice != "0" and points > 0:`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a check to your while loop and a condition to the body of the loop that notifies user when all the points are spent:

```
points = 30


Att = [["Strength", 0] , ["Health" , 0] , ["Wisdom" , 0] , ["Dexterity" , 0]]

    choice = ""

    while choice != "0" and points > 0:

            print ("\nYou have" , points , "points remaining")


        # ...
        # (code same as in question)


        elif choice == "0":


            input("Press enter if sure you have finished: ")

        # If points have gone below 0, notify user
        if points <= 0:

            print("You ran out of points!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Choices 3, 4, and 5 should be invalid when the user has 0 points left to allocate. So you could add an `if` condition right under each of those 3 that check if the user can allocate more points. For example:

```
elif choice == "2":
    if points > 0:    # Check if the player actually has the points to spend...
        s = int(input("\nAdd points to Strength: "))
        if s > points:    # Don't let the user allocate more points than he has left
            s = points
        Att [0][1] = Att [0][1] + s
        points = points - s
    else:
        print("No more points to allocate!")    # Your error message of choice
```

You will have to above similar code to the other stat allocation choices. If you want, you could also add a single condition to your outer `while` loop to shorten the amount of code, but this would not allow the user to view their stats (option 1) if their points falls to zero.

Comment: Excellent.. thanks! Is there anyway to quickly indent all of you r tabs when adding extra loops?

Comment: In Stack Overflow or in your IDE? Your IDE (should) indent for you, if not you have your choice between spaces and tabs... In Stack Overflow, slam the space key a lot or copy and past 4 spaces for each indentation level.